# How to set keywordprg to call a lua function in neovim?

Tags: neovim, options, vimscript-lua, lua

A plugin *unidentified* is setting the `keywordprg` option to `:Man` but I want it to be LSP based.

So I attempted

```
set keywordprg=:lua\ vim.lsp.buf.signature_help()
```

but it gives me the following error and I press <kbd>K</kbd> on a *NOTE: it for some reason works with vimls but not with pyright of rust-analyzer* keyword:

```
E5107: Error loading lua [string ":lua"]:1: '=' expected near '<eof>'
```

So how may I fix this error?

Comment: I found that the function which actually does this is ```vim.lsp.buf.hover()``` so mapped it but this would be nicer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`'keywordprg'` setting](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27keywordprg%27) can take an Ex command (starting with `:`), but when it does, the Ex command needs to be able to take an argument, and you can't pass one to a Lua function using `:lua` that way.

The simplest way around this is to define a new [user-defined command](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#user-commands) that calls the LSP function with the passed arguments and then use that in `'keywordprg'`.

In your case of calling one of the LSP functions, it's a bit odd that those take into consideration the current location, rather than getting an argument with the term to look up... One alternative here would be to have the user-defined command just ignore its arguments and simply call the LSP function with no arguments at all.

For example:

```
command -nargs=+ LspHover lua vim.lsp.buf.hover()
```

And then you could use:

```
set keywordprg=:LspHover
```